# Free Version Control and Issue Tracking System

Tags: version-control, issue-tracking

What are the most convenient, intuitive and easy to use Freeware Version ControlSystem and Issue Tracking system for home PC (without a LAN)?

Note that, GUIs are a must for both.

Comment: It would help if you would say what is your development environment - Visual Studio? Eclipse? NetBeans? notepad? ;) In some cases the vcs is already built in.

Answer (score 8):

Install your own copy of [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), it runs by default with SQLite so you won't need a database server (I guess the home computer doesn't have many resources).

For Version Control SVN will be just fine, if you use Windows try [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) for a faster setup.

Comment: I won't run into a discussion about GIT vs SVN here ;)

Comment: If you choose to use svn, TortoiseSVN is a very good client in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) for issue tracking/project management, and Git for version control. Redmine supports most SCM:s like CVS, Subversion, Git, Darcs, Mercurial, and Bazaar.

**Redmine features:**

- Multiple projects support
- Flexible role based access control
- Flexible issue tracking system
- Gantt chart and calendar
- News, documents & files management
- Feeds & email notifications
- Per project wiki
- Per project forums
- Time tracking
- Custom fields for issues, time-entries, projects and users
- SCM integration (SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs)
- Issue creation via email
- Multiple LDAP authentication support
- User self-registration support
- Multilanguage support
- Multiple databases support

For extremely easy installation, Redmine can be installed using [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine), available for Windows, Mac and Linux. Bitnami will install all required dependencies for you and everything may be uninstalled just as easily.

Edit: For Windows, Subversion + TortoiseSVN is probably your best bet for version control.

Comment: RedMine is great and IMHO it's development is more active than Trac.

Comment: Isn't GIT a bit rough on the edge on windows? It's great on Linux though.

Comment: Yes, BitNami rocks if you want to setup something quickly. Bitnami also has subversion installers

Comment: Redmine is fantastic. It beats Trac hands-down if you have multiple projects. TortoiseHg is pretty much on par with TortoiseSVN, by the way, if you're looking for a Windows-friendly DVCS

Answer (score 3):

There's a **100% always free hosted private bug tracker** available at https://www.hostedredmine.com/

By using that you don't even have to worry about setting up, managing and backing up your own server.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an online hosted version. [Project Locker](https://www.projectlocker.com) provide source control and issue tracking and have a free plan (up to 500MB). [Beanstalk](http://www.beanstalkapp.com/) also do online source control (100MB).

You can use any of the free UI applications to access the source control repositories (such as [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/), etc..)

Comment: To access Beanstalk you need to access Internet right?

Comment: I understood the question to mean that there was only a single PC (ie. no servers), not that the PC had no access to the internet.

Comment: I guess the question is ambiguous about that

Answer (score 1):

For version control I use Visual SVN which is a setup for a windows based user (takes care of all the install details of apache, bsd, etc.).  It just works and is easy to use/manage.  Then you need an SVN client - Tortoise is probably the best for it's windows explorer integration.  This is free.  If you want SVN integration in Visual Studio then you may want to splurge on a copy of Visual SVN for your client!

Also regarding version control don't underestimate the power of CodePlex or Google Code!  As long as you don't mind people looking at your work (IE not for secret stuff) then this is a great resource that requires far less management on your part.  Also great for distributed teams!

For bug and defect tracking you can't beat [CounterSoft's Gemini](http://www.countersoft.com/home.aspx) product.  This is a web based tool that allows you to track projects, bugs, call tickets, etc.  Very nice for the professional consultant.

If you need something more robust for a bigger team and a team that is agile specific then take a look at [VersionOne's](http://www.versionone.com/) products.  Their first year of the basic package is free!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVN/CVS, which has loads of GUI utilities to back it up on almost every OS out there. It is rock stable.
For issue tracking bugzilla is just perfect for any level of expertise and it integrates well.
Web based interface is also pretty simple and intuitive.

Comment: Please, don't even mention CVS! It's - fortunately - dead and buried deep down. SVN is an entirely different animal. You can't even rename a file in CVS!

Comment: I agree with you, SVN is definitely a very good upgrade to CVS.